# Search Suggest feature of my client's website doesn't work in Firefox but does work in Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, bigcommerce

My client's website https://universityframes.co.uk home page search bar has a search suggest feature which doesn't work in Firefox but does work in Chrome and Safari. I've checked if Firefox blocks a content (codes) of the site that is responsible for search suggest feature but it's not. It's really difficult for me to debug since console doesn't show error related to it. What could be causing the issue and what could be done? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see some errors in the console:

[image: console errors]

You can fix your issue by defining the `event` variable in here:

```js
$('.searchBox').keyup(function (event) {
                                // ^ You are missing this variable
```

#### Why does it work in other browsers?

In the [specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-window-extensions), the current event gets exposed in the window as `window.event`. Using that copy of the event is discouraged, and can result in a non accurate event being accessed.

Directly from the spec:

> Web developers are strongly encouraged to instead rely on the Event object passed to event listeners, as that will result in more portable code. This attribute is not available in workers or worklets, and is inaccurate for events dispatched in shadow trees.

If you have a read at mdn [Window.event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event), you can see that from Firefox 63 that copy of the event has been put behind a flag (sort of removed).

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot Ignacio. I will definitely fix the issue using your suggestion. I now understand the cause of the issue because of you. Thanks again

Comment: If it does resolve the issue, would you mind marking this as the answer to your question? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes I will. It will be my pleasure.

Comment: After doing your suggestion, the issue has been fixed. Thank you so much Ignacio